How to get Windows File Explorer to sort in alphanumeric order of filename
This is a question about the Windows Explorer sorted order.  It seems a basic question but I have not found an answer. Here I use Python to show the correct order and a screenshot to show the Windows 11 order. Windows is parsing the name and treating a sequence of digits as a single value.  My question is how to configure Widows to display the names in the expected order?
import os
direc = './test/'
if not os.path.isdir(direc):
    os.makedirs(direc)
files = ['a02.txt', 'a3a.txt', 'a03.txt', 'a04.txt', 'a2a.txt']
for file in files:
    open(direc+file, 'a')
for filename in os.listdir(direc):
    print(filename)

Result (as expected):
a02.txt
a03.txt
a04.txt
a2a.txt
a3a.txt

Screenshot of Windows 11 File Explorer:


Configuring Windows is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Operating system questions (unless you're actually writing code for one) are off-topic here. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is strictly for programming related questions.

You can try disabling "numerical sorting" like this

regedit.exe
Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
Create a DWORD 32-bit entry with name NoStrCmpLogical and set value to 1
Restart


@JitterThat works, many thanks.Apologies for raising an off-topic question.
